# Vue Chart JS and options reactivity

Tags: vue.js, charts, vuejs2, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to recreate the doughnut to pie change in behavior as seen here: 
https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scriptable/pie.html

I'm using VueJS version of Chart JS and after recreating this it seems to not be reactive at all.

Here is the method that I use to change the chart to the other one:

```
togglePieDoughnut() {
  this.options.cutoutPercentage = 50;
}
```

As you can see it does not work as intended, even tough I used reactiveprop mixin.

[image: Edit Vue Chart.js add label]

EDIT: To be precise I want to recreate the chart update behaviour as seen in the example on chartjs.org website. I do not want to rerender the chart, rather update it so the transition remains smooth.

Comment: The link in the question above is broken. It appears that it may have been referencing https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scriptable/pie.html [as of 2022-08-31]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the issue is the template isn't reacting to the data changes. Best way to force template re-render is to bind a **key**, for our example, we are changing this value, the template will update when its changed:

```
:key="options.cutoutPercentage"
```

Codepen example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-chartjs-demo-t8vxu?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: The thing is it will rerender the chart but I want to update it so that this animation works as in the example from Chart JS creators.

Comment: Can you please reference the Chart JS example. Here i have removed all the transition animations from the chart: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-chartjs-demo-6u56l

Comment: The link is in the question: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scriptable/pie.html

Answer (score 1):

What if we add a watch to the options variable and rerender the chart when it happens?

```
watch: {
    options: function() {
      this._chart.destroy();
      this.renderChart(this.donut, this.options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Same as other answers- the chart rerenders which mean there is no smooth animation that you can see in original chart js example.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the code of Piechart.vue, it seems that it only render one time on mounted. Thats why when changing the options, it not gonna reflected in the chart because there is no function to rerender.

The only way is you have to remove the old pie chart and create a new one when options changed. There's a lot of way to do the force re-render, but still the cleanest way is as procoib said, attach a key to it.

Comment: The thing is, even though rerendering works, the chart update loses its appeal. It looks more nice when you see the cutout appear or disappear within the chart, not the whole chart being recreated from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

When using object as `props` and update one property in it, the `reactivity system` will not trigger the change, because the object is the same and only one property updated. Thus, the child component will not get the updated value.

What can you do is to recreated the object with the updated property. See below code:

```
this.options = Object.assign({}, this.options, { cutoutPercentage: 50 });
```

And in the child component, use `watcher` re-render the chart

```
  watch: {
    options(newVal) {
    }
  }
```